# Cómo imprimir caracteres de una frase alternados desde el inicio y desde el final?

Tags: c#, array, ciclos

tengo una duda acerca de un ejercicio que me dieron, es sobre imprimir las letras de una frase alternadamente, es decir, la primera del comienzo ,la segunda del final y así recorrer toda la frase del derecho al revés.

Algo más o menos así: **Hola**

H A O L L O A H

Les paso el código de lo que avancé:

```
string frase = "";
        char[] caracteresFrase;
        int letrasFrase = 0, conDerecho = 0, conReves = 0;
        bool flag = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa una frase: ");
        frase = Console.ReadLine();
        letrasFrase = frase.Length;          
        caracteresFrase = frase.ToCharArray();


        while(conDerecho == letrasFrase && conReves == 0){
            while(flag == true || conDerecho == caracteresFrase.Length){
                Console.WriteLine(caracteresFrase[conDerecho]);
                flag = false;
                conDerecho ++;
            }
            while(flag == false || conReves == 0){
                conReves = caracteresFrase.Length;
                caracteresFrase[] = conReves;
                Console.WriteLine(caracteresFrase[conReves]);
                conReves --;
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

El código no me muestra nada, a mi parecer hay una falla en los arrays que por ignorancia no la encuentro. De antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Tu código no compila. La sentencia `caracteresFrase[] = conReves;` no es válida. ¿Seguro que copiastes bien el código?

Comment: Si lo copié bien, lo que pasa es que está mal hecho, soy principiante en C#

Comment: Pero cuando dices que el código no muestra nada, da la impresión que al menos pudistes correr el programa. En el estado acual, no corre, sino que da error de compilación, pero no compartistes ninguna información sobre este error. Es importante que las preguntas incluyan toda la información relevante.

Comment: Sólo me pide ingresar frase en consola, pongo la frase y no sale nada, al presionar tecla cualquiera la consola se cierra.

Comment: Entonces vuelvo a lo que dije al principio. El código que corres y el que has copiado en la pregunta no son iguales. Porque el que tu tienes evidentemente al menos compila. Pero este código no compila.

Comment: [Aqui hay un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/1d958e16-c1f4-4051-8120-603129dbf227/como-mezclar-letras-en-una-palabra-en-una-frase-en-c?forum=vcses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para imprimir la frase en ese formato medio invertido, solo se necesita un bucle sencillo. A cada iteración, aprovechas el mismo índice para imprimir el caracter contando desde el principio de la frase, pero también para imprimir el otro caracter contando a partir del final de la frase:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Ingresa una frase: ");
 string frase = Console.ReadLine();

 for (int i = 0; i < frase.Length; i++)
 {
    Console.Write(frase[i]);                    // contando del principio
    Console.Write(frase[frase.Length - (i+1)]); // contando del final
 }
 Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Me sirvió hermano, muchas gracias en serio :)